# Check if an object is created or not C++

Tags: c++, class, object, visual-studio-2005, declaration

I have the following piece of code -

```
string classNeeded;//set to either "Max" or "Min"

if(strcmp(classNeeded, "Max") == 0)
{

    Maximum maxi;//object of class Maximum declared

}
else
{

    Minimum mini;//object of class Minimum declared

}

while(/*Conditions*/)
{

    //Some processing
    //Use maxi or mini depending on which one is declared

}
```

I need to check if maxi is declared and use it or if it is not declared, use mini. How do I check if an object is declared or not in C++ Visual Studio 2005?

P.S.: I'm new to coding in VS2005 C++

Comment: `mini` and `maxi` aren't accessible outside of the block scopes. If the classes are related, you can use a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Using the C function `strcmp` to compare a C++ `std::string` object?

Comment: Post *real* code please. And if that `string` type comes from the same source so many other questions on SO seem to source it (`typedef`ed in come coursework header file as `char*`) its just plain yuck.

Answer (score 5):

You can't check if an object in the local scope is created at runtime. You can't even make a decision on that. It either is or it isn't, and is determinable by simply reading the code. What you're doing now is creating 2 objects in two seperate scopes. They don't exist outside the scope in which they are created, so you can't use them later, down in your while loop.  You could use pointers with dynamic allocation, but a better idea is to factor out your while loop into a pair of overloaded functions.

```
void DoIt(Maximum maxi)
{
    while(/*Conditions*/)
    {
        //Some processing
        //Use maxi
    }
}

void DoIt(Minimum mini)
{
    while(/*Conditions*/)
    {
        //Some processing
        //Use mini
    }
}
```

Then:

```
if(strcmp(classNeeded, "Max") == 0) // no comment
{
    DoIt(Maximum());
}
else
{
    DoIt(Minimum());
}
```

If the code in the while loop looks identical for both functions, just with a different object, you could use a template instead.

```
template<typename T>
void DoIt(T& object)
{
   ...
}
```